# Add Transitions for Accordion

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, jquery, product-view

How to add slide transitions when product description, additional data accordion is clicked.

Is this code needs to be edited in app.js

```
function toggleClasses(clickedItem, group) {
            var index = group.index(clickedItem);
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
                groups[i].removeClass('current');
                groups[i].eq(index).addClass('current');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

load noConflict.js after app.js to resolve this issue . 
(noConflict.js should contain the following code)
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();